# PHP checking if file exists on webp image not working

Tags: php, function, webp

So i'm trying to check if there is a webp image format on the url retrieved from `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`

This is not working how I would expect though.
Here is the code im working with:

```
if (!file_exists($thePostThumbUrl))
    $thePostThumbUrl = str_replace("_result.webp", "." . $ext, $thePostThumbUrl);
```

if I echo the thumb url it gets the correct image with a .webp format

```
echo $thePostThumbUrl . '<br/ >';
```

Displays:

image url + `_result.webp`

I know the version of PHP im working with is `PHP/5.6.30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so as Akintunde suggested, the file_exists function wont work with the url of the image. So the code needed to be modified to use the server path instead.

This code does the trick:

```
$ext = pathinfo($thePostThumbUrl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$thePostThumbPath = str_replace("http://localhost", "", $thePostThumbUrl);
if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $thePostThumbPath)) {
    $thePostThumbUrl = str_replace("_result.webp", "." . $ext, $thePostThumbUrl);
}
```

Thansk Akintunde for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that checks whether a given image exists in webp format on the server:

```
function webpExists($img_src){
  $env = array("YOUR_LOCAL_ENV", "YOUR_STAGING_ENV", "YOUR_PROD_ENV");
  $img_src_webp = str_replace(array(".jpeg", ".png", ".jpg"), ".webp", $img_src);
  $img_path = str_replace($env, "", $img_src_webp);
  return file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $img_path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CURL for this case because it's a URL.

Example:

```
function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but won't give it a downvote as maybe I didn't implement it correctly. See my answer for how I solve the problem. thanks anyway Juan :)